# How can I debug the TTFB in WP?

Tags: performance, debug, configuration

I'm developing a WP theme, based on _s default theme with WP 4.1.1.
I keep getting a TTFB(time to first byte) of 22s, consistently both on the front and back of the site, while on localhost.

Here's a print from DevTools:
[image]

I'm using the Debug Bar plugin, so I can see on the Queries and Profiler tabs that this is not a database or execution time problem(the sum of both takes 700ms). I guess it's not a rewrite problem either, since it behaves the same on the default permalink structure.
Other wordpress sites on my www don't have the same problem, so I'm discarding the server configuration. I also tried to load in incognito mode, without any difference.

Is there a way to debug this a little deeper?

Comment: Try deactivating all plugins - if that fixes it, reactivate one by one.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the first things I tried. I used the Duplicator plugin to clone the theme without plugins, but it's the same. This is the only site I have with 4.1.1 WP version. Maybe something related?

Comment: What are you using for local development?

Comment: WAMPServer 2.5(64bits).

Comment: Didn't found the reason why, but changing the path to my MySQL hostname, on wp-config.php, from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` did the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found some plugins and tools that can help with this:

- [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)
- [Laps](https://github.com/Rarst/laps)
- [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) with some add-ons([Slow Actions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-slow-actions/), [Rewrite Rules](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-rewrite-rules/), etc.)

If you really wanna go deep, try using [Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind).
Not the most friendly tool, but it'll do the job.

Be aware that some of this tools will also have an impact on performance.